# What is a better way of saying modest budget?

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

I am trying to come up with a word or words to describe someone's financial situation that is not too low or too high.  In other words, they can afford nice things (not low end), but they don't have or want to spend a lot of money on over-the-top, high-end items. I don't want to imply they have little means or are cheap.

I am writing a blog on interior design, cooking, and lifestyle.  On my "About Me" page, the first paragraph states the following:

> Creating a rich lifestyle on a modest budget can be challenging but also rewarding. I’m a firm believer that you don’t have to spend a fortune to have a well-designed home and pleasurable experiences you love sharing with family and friends.  Inspiration and ideas are everywhere -- at a museum, outside in nature, online, in a book or at a restaurant.

Comment: What don't you like about *modest* itself?

Comment: If you made your description more clear, you might more help on a site dealing with writing…

Comment: To me modest says: 1) just adequate; 2) okay, not great; 3) bargain basement.

Comment: Well, here's my take:  ***Creating a fulfilling lifestyle on a limited budget is challenging but also rewarding.*** [Normally, I charge for that.] Also: moderate budget

Comment: What is your emphasis ...  meager budget,  inadequate bugdet, minuscule budget, miserly budget

Comment: @Lambie, to me "limited budget" suggests a tighter constraint than "modest budget", modest sounds OK to me. After all most people's budgets are modest compared to those of the Kardahians and the Beckhams, it depends who you're comparing yourself with.

Comment: @BoldBen  Modest and limited are just  euphemisms for "not a lot of money". I never said modest is not just fine. The OP asked for another term. And I think you meant Kardashian, right?

Comment: @Lambie I didn't mean to criticise, just to say that I thought that "limited" was further away from the OP's requirement than "modest" which seems perfect to me, I can't see the OP's problem with it. And you're right I did mean Kardashians, but my finger missed the 's' on the virtual keyboard:-\

Comment: I agree limited does seem to say one has fewer funds than someone who has a modest budget.  I do think a moderate budget, as Lambie suggested, is more than a limited budget, a little more than a modest budget, and less than an adequate budget.

Comment: Thank you, all, for your comments and suggestions.  I have decided to use "moderate budget."  Thanks, Lambie!

Comment: I'm struggling to decide whether or not this should be classed as Writing Advice and thus POB.

Answer (score 1):

Go for something more creative and metaphorical. All the expressions like *modest budget* are over-used and make people fall asleep. For example:

> ...create a filet mignon lifestyle on a roast beef budget...
>
> ...live a Godiva life on a Hershey's salary...

You get the idea :-)

Comment: I really like your thinking, Johnny!  Very creative and memorable.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Really, this question is asking for writing advice, and I rarely upvote answers to off-topic questions. But this deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

consider a **thrifty** budget. [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/thrifty)

> mindful of the future in spending money; careful and diligent in the
>   use of resources

As is this website:  [Fashionable Gear on a **Thrifty Budget**](http://www.uptowncheapskate.com/fashionable-gear-thrifty-budget/)

Comment: A person may be thrifty but I would not say a budget is.

Answer (score 0):

I know where you coming from with your intention of describing a budget. But you can't describe a budget using a description of a person if you know what I mean. I would describe as "smart" a person that has the money to buy things or do things but doesn't want to spend money on high-end items. In other word, it means a person that spends his/her money wisely and knows how to prioritize where his/her money goes. The only word I can think that would fit this would be "smart budget". It would mean to use your budget wisely but it doesn't mean the person is cheap.

Comment: jimm101, this is a really good take on finding a word I was looking for!  I think I will use your suggestion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If "on a modest budget" sounds *too* restrictive to you, then you might consider just "on a budget", which implies that there's a limit — we're not talking about super-wealthy, money-is-no-object types — without necessarily implying that it's a particularly low one.

Comment: This is true, Ruakh!  I didn't think to look at it like that.  Thanks.